# simulating a 'Super exception' in Python

Tags: python, exception, discord, super

for the past days I have been struggling to find a method to remotely break a function by raising an Exception. I have tried many methods, but the functions never initiate from on_guild_channel_create.

The documentation for the library (discordpy):
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#

**Example 1:**

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=2.0)
async def cancel_func(mm_channel):
    async for m in mm_channel.history(limit=100):
        if any(role.name in high_perms_list for role in m.author.roles) and m.content.lower() == '$cancel':
            raise ExitError
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(mm_channel):
    if mm_channel.category.id == limiteds_MM_category_id:
        cancel_func.start(mm_channel)
```

returns: discord.ext.tasks Unhandled exception in internal background task 'cancel_func'.

**Example 2:**

```
async def cancel_func(mm_channel):
    def check(m):
        return any(role.name in high_perms_list for role in m.author.roles) and m.channel == mm_channel

    m = await bot.wait_for('message',check=check)

    if m.content == '$cancel':
        raise ExitError
    else:
        cancel_func(mm_channel)

async def on_guild_channel_create(mm_channel):
       cancel_func(mm_channel)
```

This example works, however it halts the functionality of on_guild_channel_create due to the wait_for event handler. Which should not happen.